# The system cannot find the file specified using subprocess Popen and only works on desktop with simple bat files

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

In Idle I am getting the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

While trying to open a file in a folder on my desktop.

```py
p = Popen("open.bat", cwd=r"C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\Project")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Is the lines that are opening the file.

One thing to note, this works if I have a simple batch file on my desktop that just echos a word but doesn't for another batch doing other stuff in my project folder. If I put the simple batch file in my project folder it also does not work. I am POSITIVE I have the right path because I copy and paste it from the properties window. I also tried to make a shortcut of the bat file but noticed that it's path is the same as the original.

I want the script to run the file, so if there is anything that I should change, please let me know.

PS: Running on Python 3.7

Comment: Have you considered changing the the batch file's directory before trying to open it? or at least use the full path the batch file?

Comment: I tried moving the file to different locations if that is what you are wondering. It works outside of the intended directory, but the problem is that it needs to be in there to do other processes located in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed this by ditching subprocess for os

```py
os.chdir(r"path")
os.startfile(r"file.bat")
```

still not sure why subprocess was having trouble with the same exact task. Anyways, I advise using this since so far it has worked every time

Comment: That's what I advised you to do in my comment, isn't it?